# select() max sockets

Tags: c++, sockets, select, asynchronous

Just more asynchronous stuff!

Alright, so I now have a working asynchronous socket program for my main chatting application, and it's working really well! However I have one concern..

While using select() what is the maximum number of file descriptors that I can use in each set? I've read about a limit of 1024...

If that limit is indeed hard coded and I can't FD_SETSIZE the limit any higher, should I spawn another thread once I reach that limit? Or something else? Is this even a concern?

Comment: Alright, sounds like I'm stuck with *nix if I'm going to use poll correct?

Comment: Windows has WSAPoll() which works very much like poll().

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, the FD_SETSIZE has a limit of 1024. You can easily check that by looking at the select.h header. People have tried to increase the limit, but the reports vary from "working" to "crashing" after a while. If you need that many connections, use `poll` instead.

[A very good article to read.](http://www.moythreads.com/wordpress/2009/12/22/select-system-call-limitation/)

Comment: Thank you for the article! And the answer!

Answer (score 3):

If you are programming under a Posix compliant system, you should be able to use the poll() function instead of select() and this will do away with the limit that you mention.  Alternatively, you can call select() multiple times in succession but be certain to use a relatively short timeout.

Comment: using select() multiple times wont work, since the limit lies with the FDs that are larger than the FD_SETSIZE. That is, as soon as a fd larger than 1024 is used, it will break. Read carefully the notes section on man pages.

Comment: It will work if you reconstruct the set for a new set of handles or if you use a different set altogether.   I have already done this under windows.

Comment: For my test system, that's actually what I ended up doing. I'm thinking about simply spawning new threads for each multiple of 1024

Comment: @JonTrauntvein IIRC, on Windows, FD_SETSIZE is the number of sockets that can be in a set, but in Linux, it's **the maximum socket number** (plus one) that can be in a set. So if FD_SETSIZE is 1024, and you have 1025 sockets, one of them will be numbered 1025, and you can't use it. (Approximately)

Answer (score 3):

For really large numbers of sockets look into using a library like [`libevent`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libevent).

The library can abstract several OS-specific advanced features like /dev/poll, kqueue, epoll, and event ports. With these you can handle really vast numbers of connections.

Comment: Just took a look at it, I'll give it a try!

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what OS you're using, but for most, if you want to use file descriptors above 1024 with select, you can `#define FD_SETSIZE` to be a larger number BEFORE #including sys/socket.h.  Unfortunately, this doesn't work on Linux.

Comment: I had read something about that, and the server may be on several operating systems, unfortunately.