# What is the maximum number of channels that a selector can select?

Tags: java, sockets, nio

I want to know how many channels can a selector can handle at maximum? I'm familiar with common I/O algorithms, but I don't know in `NIO` whether I can use a selector for handling (for example) 10000 sockets. Should use a number of threads and have a selector in each for handling a specific number of sockets?

While I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243585/how-many-connections-can-selector-in-java-nio-select-one-at-a-time?rq=1), it didn't address this specific question.

Comment: The second response to the question you linked seems to answer this question: if you're using less than 10,000 connections, the problem is likely elsewhere. Defining a specific maximum may not be possible without knowing a lot about the hardware it's on and other factors using resources.

Comment: @NathanielFord The second response is just unsourced rumour actually, and has now been deleted due to adverse comment. It is also irrelevant to the question that was asked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no limit other than the number of socket descriptors. Some platforms have underlying limits, but NIO works around them with multiple OS selectors per `Selector.`

There was a limit up to about Java 1.4.1 but it's long gone.

> Should use a number of threads and have a selector in each for handling a specific number of sockets?

It's possible, but I don't really see why you should. Maybe the peers might get more regular service that way, it depends what your code has to do with every request.